# Replace part of text from column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to replace this following

| Numeric Route | Alphanumeric Route |
| --- | --- |
| 1571 | T57A |
| 2212 | P21B |
| 3123 | A12C |
| 421 | E21 |
| 2473 | P21C |

I've been searching in the web by now i have found the following

```
mapping = { 1:'T', 2:'P', 3:'A', 4:'E'}
for k, v in mapping.items():
    k = str(k)
    evaluate2['Alphanumeric Route'] = evaluate2['Numeric Route'].str.replace('^' + k + '{1}', v, case=False, regex=True)
```

By this I get

| Numeric Route | Alphanumeric Route |
| --- | --- |
| 1571 | T571 |
| 2212 | P212 |
| 3123 | A123 |
| 421 | E21 |
| 2473 | P213 |

But I still stuck in the last letter, because it depends on the len of the numeric if len is 3 do nothing but if te len is 4 the rule is the following

```
mapping2 = { 1:'A', 2:'B', 3:'C', 4:'D', 5:'E'}
```

**PS**: for the second part I have tried the following but not works

```
for k, v in mapping2.items():
    k = str(k)
    evaluate2['Línea'] = evaluate2['Línea'].apply(lambda x: x if len(x) < 4 else x.replace(r'.*[' + k + ']$', v))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use look-behind utility of regex:

```
import pandas as pd

evaluate2 = pd.DataFrame({'Numeric Route':['1571','2212','3123','421','2473']})

evaluate2['Alphanumeric Route'] = evaluate2['Numeric Route']

mapping = { 1:'T', 2:'P', 3:'A', 4:'E'}
mapping2 = { 1:'A', 2:'B', 3:'C', 4:'D', 5:'E'}

for k, v in mapping.items():
    k = str(k)
    evaluate2['Alphanumeric Route'] = evaluate2['Alphanumeric Route'].str.replace('^' + k + '{1}', v, 
            case=False, regex=True)

for k, v in mapping2.items():
    k = str(k)
    evaluate2['Alphanumeric Route'] = evaluate2['Alphanumeric Route'].str.replace('(?<=.{3})'+k+'$', v,
            case=False, regex=True)


print(evaluate2)
```

I used the same code for doing both operations, just changed the regex part.

`(?<=...)` : Look-behind checks if the **fixed length** regex exists without consuming or including it in primary regex.

Output:

```
  Numeric Route Alphanumeric Route
0          1571               T57A
1          2212               P21B
2          3123               A12C
3           421                E21
4          2473               P47C
```

Now there are better ways to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

evaluate2 = pd.DataFrame({'Numeric Route':['1571','2212','3123','421','2473']})

mapping = { 1:'T', 2:'P', 3:'A', 4:'E'}
mapping2 = { 1:'A', 2:'B', 3:'C', 4:'D', 5:'E'}

N_mapping = {'^'+str(key):value for key,value in mapping.items()}
N_mapping2 = {'(?<=.{3})'+str(key)+'$':value for key,value in mapping.items()}

evaluate2['Alphanumeric Route'] = evaluate2['Numeric Route'].replace(N_mapping,regex=True)

evaluate2['Alphanumeric Route'] = evaluate2['Alphanumeric Route'].replace(N_mapping2,regex=True)


print(evaluate2)
```

Output:

(same as above)

Comment: thanks, I only modified in N_mapping2 the last part changed by mappin2.items() and work perfect